# PHP __get and Private class variables

Tags: php, oop

Assuming one has an abstract base class `foo` with `__get()` defined, and a child class `bar` which inherits from `foo` with a private variable `$var`, will the parent `__get()` be called when trying to access the private `$var` from outside the class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

```
<?php
    abstract class foo
    {
        public function __get($var)
        {
            echo "Parent (Foo) __get() called for $var\n";
        }
    }

   class bar extends foo
   {
        private $var;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->var = "25\n";
        }

        public function getVar()
        {
            return $this->var;
        }
    }

    $obj = new bar();
    echo $obj->var;
    echo $obj->getVar();
?>
```

output:

$ php test.php

Parent (Foo) __get() called for var

25

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  `__get()` and `__set()` (and `__call()` for that matter) are invoked when a data member is accessed that is not visible to the current execution.

In this case, `$var` is private, so accessing it publicly will invoke the `__get()` hook.